# How to route groupchat message in Strophe

Tags: routes, xmpp, ejabberd, strophe

I have an incoming message that looks like this...

```
<message 
    from='pinza@some.com' 
    to='tulyar@some.com' 
    type='groupchat' 
    xmlns='jabber:message:group_chat_test'>

    <body>Here is my message.</body>
</message>
```

In my routes.js file I'm trying to route the message based on something other than the content of the body - specifically I want to route it based on the custom namespace (so I can have different groupchat message types that get handled by different controllers) so I try this...

```
bind.query('message[type="groupchat"][xmlns="jabber:message:group_chat_test"]')
  .to(SD.Messenger.Room, "groupchat_test");
```

But the message goes into the ether rather than reaching the group_chat_test controller. We do similar things to this with <iq>'s but it doesn't seem to work with groupchat messages.

Am I missing something? Should I be able to query groupchat messages this way? Is there some other way I can do it?

FYI, my current workaround is this hack...

```
bind.query('message[type="groupchat"]').to(SD.Messenger.Room, "all_groupchat_msgs");
```

With this in controllers.js

```
SD.Messenger.Room.prototype.all_groupchat_msgs = function() {
   // test the body of the incoming stanza and 
   // based on it's contents do different things...
};
```

(Using Ejabberd, Bosh, Stroph)

Answer (score 1):

you cannot change the namespace of the main XMPP stanzas message, iq and presence. You can only have custom namespaces on the child elements of those.

When your IQs work then you have probably your custom namespace in one of the child elements.

examples:

```
<iq type='get' id='1' to='user@server.com/resource'>
   <query xmlns='my-custom-ns'>
      payload
   </query>
</iq>


<message type='groupchat' to='room@muc.server.com'>
   <x xmlns='my-custom-ns'>
      payload
   </x>
</message>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the approach that worked...
Add a custom attribute...

```
<message 
    from='pinza@some.com' 
    to='tulyar@some.com' 
    type='groupchat' 
    custom_subtype='my_custom_type'>

    <body>Here is my message.</body>
</message>
```

Create a route that filers on that custom attribute

```
bind.query('message[type="groupchat"][custom_subtype="my_custom_type"]')
  .to(Room, "controller_for_my_custom_type");
```